# c# MP3 ID3 data (without taglib)

Tags: c#, mp3, id3

I found a piece of code that displays ID3 data, but can't figure out how it works for thumbnail. What I'm looking for is to display the file's artwork in a pictureBox.

```
            //get   title   of   song; 
            sTitle = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 3, 30);

            //get   singer; 
            sSinger = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 33, 30);

            //get   album; 
            sAlbum = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 63, 30);

            //get   Year   of   publish; 
            sYear = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 93, 4);

            //get   Comment; 
            sComm = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 97, 30);
```

If the data is stored this way:
[image: img]

Then where do I find the artwork (cover of the album)?
I don't see it in the Table from wikipedia, but it's stored somewhere.

Comment: _I found a piece of code that displays ID3 data, but can't figure out how it works._ ??? How could we help you without knowing what code yu are talking about??

Comment: Why not use a tag library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided only supports ID3v1.  That version does not support images.

However, the [ID3v2 tag](http://id3.org/Developer%20Information) *does* support images.  See section 4.15 of the 2.3 informal standard for an explanation of the "attached image" tag. Note that you'll need to write a full ID3v2 parser if you wish to read out the image without a tag library.

Good luck!